# How does the DTC service work for multiple servers

Tags: sql-server, wcf, distributed-transactions

I need information or references about what should I know in ordeer to use the DTC service coss multiple servers, configurations implications, etc. The solution Im developing use several transactional WCF services and SQL server Databases that, could be located in several servers, and i dont know what the implications are, meaning if Its necessary to have one DTC serevr per server and how do they know about each other, etc...

I would appreciate any knid of collected tutorial or information that would help me to get knowledge quickly in order to have an initial base configuration working ASAP.

In advance, any contribution is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if the network is fast between all machines, you would configure the same coordinator for all machines, avoiding coordinator-to-coordinator overhead.

Here is a good link on overall MSDTC architecture: [MS DTC Architecture](http://etutorials.org/SQL/microsoft+sql+server+2000/Part+IV+Transact-SQL/Chapter+32.+Distributed+Transaction+Processing/MS+DTC+Architecture/)

and another that details how to change the default transaction coordinator: [Configure the Default Transaction Coordinator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731461.aspx)